# Разбор по членам предложения. ПГС или СИС?

Tags: синтаксис

Двое из нас поедут в столицу. 
"Двое из нас" - подлежащее, а сказуемое- поедут или поедут в столицу. Почему?

Comment: Для справки. Сказуемое может быть простым глагольным (ПГС), составным глагольным (СГС), составным именным (СИС).

Comment: Для справки. Читайте Правила сайта; там сказано, что домашние задания не выполняются.

Comment: Скорее всего, это не задание, а трудность, встреченная при его исполнении

Comment: Это не домашнее задание! Это я сам нашел пример с которым у меня трудности!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Что сделают?) поедут - ПГС

(Куда?) - в столицу - обстоятельство места

СИС состоит из глагола-связки, в том числе нулевой, и имени:( Я) был зол. (Он) строитель